# How can I exclude images from next/previous navigation?

Tags: plone

In plone I Have noticed that images are showing up in the next/previous navigation for Plone. How can I exclude content types from this navigation?

Comment: To a zeroth approximation, you can't with Archetypes content types. If you are in a position to program, the relevant piece is `buildNextPreviousQuery` in `Products.ATContentTypes.browser.nextprevious`, which is pretty straightforward.